# Sangria GraphQL Context can become too large?

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

How do you structure the the context object described [here](https://sangria-graphql.org/learn/#input-and-context-objects) in such a way that it doesn't contain every service that your schema may need?

In the example StarWars schema [all fields use the same context](https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria-playground/blob/master/app/models/SchemaDefinition.scala#L59) (CharacterRepo) to resolve.

My context could potentially contain 50 different services?

Comment: Generally, the context object needs to have access to all services that are necessary for fulfilling the GraphQL query. You can also define a GraphQL type with a limited access to a context object components as demonstrated in this test: https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria/blob/master/src/test/scala/sangria/execution/ContextPassingSpec.scala

Comment: wow thanks so much, very cool idea. I think that can help to break down the context. I'm curious, what is happening on this line? https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria/blob/master/src/test/scala/sangria/execution/ContextPassingSpec.scala#L38 field "name" resolves to what in that case?

Comment: This field is just a stub, it resolves to a `Unit`